# How to Add $ in digit using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add $ sign when any number found in my string.

ie.

"This 123 and if we add 2 in 123 than it becomes 125." //-this is string not a question.

out is like.

This $123 and if we add $2 in $123 than it becomes $125.

Comment: you have asked 2 different questions. Can you rephrase your question to make it more readable?

Comment: updated my queation..Thanks

Comment: Down voters please at least comment so I will update my question and I know whats wrong with my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like by using `regex` and `replace`'s with its `callBack` signature,

```
var str = "This 123 and if we add 2 in 123 than it becomes 125";
str = str.replace(/\d+/g, function(v){
 return "$" + v;
});

console.log(str); //This $123 and if we add $2 in $123 than it becomes $125
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s1vfg5ut/)

Comment: Thanks its work when my time is complete I will accept.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

use `regex` to add the `$` before the numbers

```js
alert("This 123 and if we add 2 in 123 than it becomes 125".replace(/(\s)(?![a-z A-Z]+)/g, " $"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "This 123 and if we add 2 in 123 than it becomes 125.".replace(/([0-9]{1,9})/g, 
function(str){
 return "$"+str;
});
document.writeln(string);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d44yawb3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var str = "This 123 and if we add 2 in 123 than it becomes";
var t = str.split(" ");
var c = 0;
var e = 0;
var d = "";
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  if (parseInt(t[i])) {
    d = d + " " + "$" + t[i]
    c += parseInt(t[i]);
    e = parseInt(t[i]);
  } else {
    d = d + " " + t[i]
  }

}
alert(d + " $" + (c - e))
```